# Sharepoint: Display multiple related lists on a single page with paging

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, office365, custom-lists

I need to display multiple sharepoint custom lists in a single page. Let me explain the requirement with following example:
List 1: User
List 1 Columns: 1. Name, 2. Age, 3. Gender, 4. DOB

List 2: Address
List 2 Coluomns: 1. UserName(reference to User list), 2. Address1, 3. Address2, 4. City

List 3: Company
List 3 Columns: 1. UserName(reference to User list), 2. Company Name

Now I need to show all these lists in a single page with paging. Let say we have 10 records in each list. and have page size of 3. Now total pages will be 4(3+3+3+1). On page index 1, lists should display 3 records each(List 1 will have paging and other two lists will have related records). On page index 2, each list will still display 3 records (Records in List 1 will change and List 2 & 3 will show new records related to current values in List 1).

Please help me getting this done in Sharepoint. **I am doing this in browser only. I have sharepoint office 365 license so I can not do any coding to achieve this.**

Regards,
Dhiman

Comment: Use JSOM , On button click append query string with your Index and fetch the data from all 3 lists. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple, use JavaScript CSOM (Client Object Model) to query these two lists and then you can build your list structure as you want in the page.

Here is an example how to do CRUD operation for SP lists in JS:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx

Once you get the data for list1 and list2, build your list as you like in the html/asp.net page.

Hope this helps.